# How to caputure HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, jvm, tomcat7

I've deployed an application in  tomcat 7.0.55 for testing.I want to capture whether "HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" is occurring or not . Following are my JVM parameters.

JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ThreadStackSize=512 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/apps/dumps/"

I don't see any file under the directory. Does it create a file under the directory or i've to manually create a file to append ?

Comment: Do you want to test the Exception being thrown on OOM? If that is the case, then I assume you must somehow get the VM to get OOM. The heapDump will occur and write its story to the location you've specified. You can also specify a filename in regard to the OOM by specifying `-XX:ErrorFile=whatever.file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as below :

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -XX:HeapDumpPath=

You can also manually generate a memory map using jmap if you know the process id:

jmap -J-d64 -dump:format=b,file=

You can use JHat to analyze the dump.

jhat "path to dump file".

By default the heap dump is created in a file called java_pid.hprof in the working directory of the VM, as in the example above. You can specify an alternative file name or directory with the -XX:HeapDumpPath= option. For example -XX:HeapDumpPath=/disk2/dumps will cause the heap dump to be generated in the /disk2/dumps directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is a permissions issue to write to the configured folder `/apps/dumps/`.

For reference - 
https://blog.gceasy.io/2015/08/14/how-to-capture-heap-dump-jmap/
https://blogs.oracle.com/LuzMestre/entry/how_to_collect_a_heap